# R: GIS / Census data - scale_fill_continuous - need to drop default legend and keep custom legend (using tidycensus)

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, legend, tidycensus

all - I've created a map of Census block groups shaded by % Families in Poverty.  Then, I've overlaid city boundaries and a map of certain types of events.  It all looks great except that the color gradient is backwards and not intuitive.  I added a scale_fill_continuous with a more intuitive scaling.  I now have two different perfectly inconsistent legends only one of which is right.  I've tried a number of solutions here on SOF (including: trying to reverse the guides; and adding guides(fill="none") and theme(legend.position = "none")) - but the minute I add a the custom legend, the default legend comes back or I get no legends at all - depending where the guides(fill="none") or theme(legend.position = "none"). Because it's GIS data, even a small dput is large. The code is below. I'm close to dropping the plots as is into PowerPoint and covering up the unwanted legend with a white box. Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

```
  p <- ggplot(cc_fam, aes(fill = per, color = per)) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf(data = urb_boundaries, fill = NA, color = "red") +
  geom_sf(data = my_sf, colour = "orange", inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~variable)
  p + scale_fill_continuous(high = "#132B43", low = "#56B1F7", name = "Percent Families in Poverty")
```

Comment: You have mapped both the fill and the color aesthetics. Try removing `color = per` from the first aes call

Comment: Perhaps just remove `color = per` from `aes()`.

Comment: Thank you both! Removing color = per worked perfectly. I might be too new to tag as an accepted answer - but if I can, I will.  Thanks again